# Chunk audio/video files for web

Tags: javascript, html, audio, stream, chunks

i see in sites like youtube, soundcloud, spotify, that they stream their contents (audio or video) in small chunks. 
For example, when i load an audio on soundcloud, the server response an small piece of the complete archive, then, before of consume this chunk, the browser sends another request with the next chunk and repeat this process until the complete file is consumed.
What is the name of this technique? How can achive this?
Currently i have an nodejs server that streams audio files and accepts range headers.

I load this files in the browser with html5 Audio API, but the browser loads the entire file and i can't able to achive the behaivor mentioned above.

This is a configuration that i need set in the client (Browser)? this is related with .m3u files?

I attach an image of the Network tab in Chrome dev tools of the behavior mentioned above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/COOCd.png

[Chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COOCd.png)

Comment: So is your backend sending the appropriate range request response headers? Can you see them in dev tools?